# JQuery UI Dialog: Call to Empty() after Clode throws Exception cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When i invoke the empty-function after closing a dialog like this:

```
$( "myselector" ).dialog( "close" ).empty()
```

i get the following error

```
cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'
```

Any Ideas whtas wrong ?

Comment: Use .dialog('destroy') instead of .empty()

Comment: have you initialized your dialog before calling `close` method?